# Avoid indirect duplicates in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I don't mean two *exactly* same rows.

My table's simple structure is something like this:

id val1 val2

val1 and val2 are used to link two objects together, and I can't know which is which because they reference the same table.

I need to avoid the following:

```
id  val1    val2
1   40      60
2   60      40
```

I can use INSERT IGNORE to avoid direct duplicates, but it doesn't work with the one above.

I'm also trying to avoid multiple queries from PHP, **so I'm asking if it is possible to do this in one SQL query that is sent from PHP.**

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: these values are user id's that are added to link players to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When inserting, just check if `val1 <= val2`, if so insert them in that order, if not switch them. With this condition you will always be sure that duplicate values result in identical inserts.

Answer (score 1):

I'd force the issue, either through application code or a database trigger, so that you can guarantee that val1 < val2 when data is inserted. Then create a unique index on (val1, val2).